# How to update multiple dropdownlists using Ajax in Asp.net-MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I have multiple identical dropdownlists created by a `@html` helper. In each dropdown, there is one option which is named "Create a new one".

When I click this option, there is popup showing up and allows me to fill out infor and create a new option. I'm totally up to this part, and get it saved to database successfully.

But what I want is as soon as I close the popup, the newly created option will also show up to other dropdownlists. What should I do? examples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try something like this:
[ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownList populated by Ajax call to controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830099/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-populated-by-ajax-call-to-controller)

when close the popup, update the drop downs